# Screen-Video with 7 FPS (in Davinci Resolve - or other tools?)

Tags: mp4, framerate, davinci-resolve, export, 25fps

I currently edit/cut a lot of computer screen recording footage. The original mp4 files have 7 FPS and I am totally happy with that quality. If I now edit the files in Davinci Resolve 16, the lowest export frame rate is at 16 FPS. 
In my case, I'd prefer an export file with 7 FPS due to lower file sizes.

Is there any way how to do that in Davinci Resolve? (I already tried Clip Attributes > Video > Custom FPS)
If not - which tool can help me?

Thank you so much!